# How to keep user authenticated long term using google api client library

Tags: ruby, authentication, google-api

#### Background

I'm working on an app that will run on a device which does not contain a browser, but I want to get the users google tasks through the google api.

Because of the lack of browser, they can't authenticate on the device, so I have it set up in such a way that they visit a website and authenticate there, then the device makes http requests to the website to get the data it needs.

#### Problem

Once I got everything working this system works out OK, the problem is it only works for a day or so before the user has to visit the website again to refresh their access token.

It would be great if the user could be authenticated for very long periods of time, or even forever (not sure if that's possible or secure). Can I get some suggestions on what people think is the best way to accomplish this kind of long term athentication?

#### Refresh tokens?

I've heard there is a way to store the user's refresh token in a database and somehow use that to refresh their access token. If this sounds like a good way, can anyone point me in the direction of an example to get this to work?

I've been using the [google api client library for ruby](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the refresh tokens. I can't help too much with the Ruby API, and honestly I just did this calling the REST api directly, but this doc should help you understand the actual calls you need to make.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Note that for a lot of their examples you need to remove the newlines for them to work.

Basically like you said, you need to send the user to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth with the access-type=offline parameter for them to give consent. This comes back with an authorization code, which you send to /o/oauth2/token. This comes back with an access token and a refresh token. You can use the access token immediately, and you store the refresh token, which never expires. When the access token expires you send the refresh token to /o/oauth2/token (note that the grant_type changes to refresh_token) to get a new access token.